# Import image GUI not appearing

Tags: java, image, user-interface

I am trying to upload an image on a GUI. Here is what my code reads right now:

```
  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(nameSearched.getImage());  
  myLabelK = new JLabel();
  myLabelK.setBounds(500,100,200,200);
  myLabelK.setIcon(icon); 
  myPanel.setLayout(null);

  myPanel.add(myLabelK);
  Validate();   
  add(myPanel);
  setVisible(true);
```

When I run my program this image is not popping up on my GUI.

The `nameSearched.getImage()` is calling a method in a different class which returns an image entered into the system. For example, Peter.jpg.

Please help me figure out how to get my image on the screen.

Comment: Are you sure the images file is in the correct directory. what is the file path you are using? Where is the image located in the file system.

Comment: Hey peeskillet...i was not aware i had to use a directory, and i was not following any path. How do i write this code?

Comment: `ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(filename);` where `filename` is the path `"Peter.jpg"`. Take a look at my anser for more info

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using `Peter.jpg` as you relative path name,

Using an IDE, you image should be ditrectly below the ProjectRoot directory

```
ProjectRootDir
           Peter.jpg
           src
```

If you wanted to have your image in an images folder:

```
use "images\Peter.jpg"

ProjectRootDir
           images
                Peter.jpg
           src
```

Maybe you want to retrieve the image like this

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Peter.jpg");
```

Another possibility, If you do this:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(nameSearched.getImage());

then nameSearched.getImage() must return either a String fie path of the image
                             or an Image object.
```

Maybe you just want `nameSearched.getImage()` to return a String from an array of `String` paths. Not sure what `nameSearched.getImage()` actually does so I can't go into further explanation or correction